# How to get the sender id from facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Say I'm A. And A sends invite to B. When B ,accepts my friend request,then i am geting request id on my page but how do i get A UID of Mine(A) on my php page?

Please help me. Am struggling since 6 hrs for this.

I am using these(see below) code for getting request_Id. But from these How can i get the SENDERS ID?

```
 <?php
    require_once('phps/fbsdk/src/facebook.php');
    $config = array
    (
      'appId' => '27c3932323897****82',
      'secret' => '******************************',
    );
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    //get the request ids from the query parameter
     $request_ids = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']);

     //build the full_request_id from request_id and user_id
      function build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id) {
      return $request_id . '_' . $user_id;
     }

     //for each request_id, build the full_request_id and delete request
     foreach ($request_ids as $request_id)
     {
     echo ("reqeust_id=".$request_id."<br>");
     $full_request_id = build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id);
     echo ("full_request_id=".$full_request_id."<br>");

    try {
     $delete_success = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
     if ($delete_success) {
        echo "Successfully deleted " . $full_request_id;}
     else {
       echo "Delete failed".$full_request_id;}
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo "error";}
    }
 ?>`
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a call to graph api (graph.facebook.com/{REQUEST_ID}) using request id you get, you will receive sender ID, you will get something like this:

```
{
  "id": "493703870648580", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Send Requests How To", 
    "id": "403223126407920"
  }, 
  "to": {
    "name": "Chris Abe Colm", 
    "id": "100003086810435"
  }, 
  "from": {
    "name": "Christine Abernathy", 
    "id": "1424840234"
  }, 
  "data": "{\"badge_of_awesomeness\":\"1\",\"social_karma\":\"5\"}", 
  "message": "Learn how to make your Android apps social", 
  "created_time": "2012-10-07T17:29:57+0000"
}
```

more about graph api: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

PS: remove your app secret from your sample

Comment: Sorry!  I tried but its not showing info like you have shown above.   i am getting requestid as 476329762424436 . And i run this in browser `http://graph.facebook.com/476329762424436`   but it showing error like this `{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}`    Why?

Comment: because you need to use access_token to get that information, if its canvas application you can get access_token through signed_request (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/) otherwise 
http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

or simply by Javascript API methods,

Comment: i guess FB PHP SDK have also some methods to get access token, you should take a look on it too

Comment: i made call to the php sdk. Now i am getting access token.  My output in browser  `request_id=476329762424436
Access Token=27c393232389736782|667e2317dc1f308f312d49d6b1c17cb8`   Now how i will make request to get the senders Id?  And also once doubt i am getting access token as   `****|*******` is this valid access token? I doubt that i am getting `|` in middle.

Comment: You should strip access token  from there to get this format graph.facebook.com/(request_id)?access_token=27c...

Comment: i used `$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();` but this is giving access token like this:-> `27c393232389736782|667e2317dc1f308f312d49d6b1c17cb8`   And once if i use this access token with my generated request id then i am unable to get output as you explained above.   i wrote:   `graph.facebook.com/(586019234745503)?access_token=27c393232389736782|667e2317dc1f308f312d49d6b1c17cb8`  Please let me know what is my mistake on the above.

Comment: while you are using FB PHP SDK you can directly use $facebook->api('/586019234745503');

Comment: i wrote like this `echo '---Output-------=>'. $facebook->api('/'.$full_request_id.'');`   but it is not displaying anything?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22810/discussion-between-derki-and-ashutosh)

Comment: Now i am able to get the  request object data  but  how to get only Senders id from this output. I think i am getting this output in json form.Check my output below

Comment: OUTPUT:   `array(6) { ["id"]=> string(26) "514484461930096_1446926141" ["application"]=> array(2) {["name"]=> string(18) "Pocket Financetest" ["id"]=> string(15) "270339389736782" } ["to"]=> array(2) {["name"]=> string(12) "Prince Singh" ["id"]=> string(10) "1446926141" } ["from"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Ashutosh Singh" ["id"]=> string(15) "100003645579131" } ["message"]=> string(16) "My Great Request" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-01-17T03:45:36+0000" }`

Comment: that means its correct, its PHP array, use $array['id'] or nested access as $array['application']['name'], etc, (you need to assign output first, eg. $array = $facebook->api('/'.$full_request_id.'');)

Comment: Yeah thanks. Finally my problem solved. I did `$array =  $facebook->api("/$full_request_id");
     $getid=$array['from']['id'] ;
     echo $getid;`